# JSON Serialize Emoji

Tags: json, swift, unicode, emoji

I need to send a message to the server which contains emojis. I read the data from CoreData, store it in dictionary and then convert it into json format.

My initial dictionary has following content

```
["0": ["chat_token": "8g9nu0Z.a3", "message": "", "user_id": "1242", "created": "2017-12-29 17:13:16"]]
```

I then convert it into JSON using following code

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: resultDict, options: [])
    if let jsonText = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) {
        return jsonText as String
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

This returns me following json string

```
{"0":{"chat_token":"8g9nu0Z.a3","message":"ð¤ð","user_id":"34","created":"2017-12-29 17:13:16"}}
```

The problem is emojis are not correctly formatted. In JSON it gets converted to `ð¤ð`

The reason I need it is to send it to the server to store the message. How do I convert emoji to json string format.

Comment: I assume that the encoding is improper...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to initialize the `String` with ASCII encoding, in which emojis doesn't exist. You should be using UTF-8.

You also shouldn't be using `NSString`, since you are returning a `String` anyways and aren't using any `NSString` specific functionality.

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: resultDict)
    if let jsonText = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
        return jsonText
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

```
"{"0":{"chat_token":"8g9nu0Z.a3","message":"","user_id":"1242","created":"2017-12-29 17:13:16"}}"
```

Comment: I quickly realized after posting the questions. And thanks for the tip about String.